# Unable to run testng program

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

I am unable to run a `testng` program as it gives `classpath` error. I have already added `testng` libraries:

> org.testng.TestNGException: 
>       Cannot find class in classpath: testngBasic

```
package mobileAutomation;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    public class testngBasic {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUP() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
    @Test
    public void getTitle() {
        String googleTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(googleTitle);
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Eclipse > Project > Clean` and then run the test cases again. It should work.